# How to implement message passing in GNU Radio?

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I need to implement message passing, my idea is to make some sort of message source (I inherit from `public gr_sync_block`) that works as a controller for another block (it has to send a message each 6 minutes).

I read that is necessary to inherit from `gnuradio::block`  -and by the way, installing grextras is mandatory-. In the `.h` file I added the `#include <gnuradio/block.h>` and inherited from block `class JDFM_API jdfm_control : public gr_sync_block, public gnuradio::block`. I know that I have redefine some things like the `gnuradio::block` constructor but I dont know what `msg_signature` is, I also don't get the relation between block's parameters and work parameter, the last thing that I am not sure is if I still can use `gnuradio-companion` if I create a block like this.

I haven't been able to find a simple example of messages implementation. If anyone can guide me or show me an example, it would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been done, by Josh Blum, and is available as part of his GNURadio extras packages on GitHub:

https://github.com/guruofquality/grextras/wiki#wiki-feature-message-passing

Enjoy!

Comment: Can you explain me what are the parameters used in msg_signature(1, 2)?

Comment: Just a casual update on this: Modern versions of GNU Radio have message passing functionality built in.